# If $F: \ell^1 \rightarrow \ell^2$ is linear, continuous and injective, then it is not surjective

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to show that if $F: \ell^1 \rightarrow \ell^2$ is linear, continuous and injective, then it is not surjective.

It's obvious that $\ell^1 \subset \ell^2$ so it can't be surjective?

Comment: What would the Bounded Inverse Theorem (or Open Mapping Theorem) imply if it were?

Comment: that $F$ is open mapping

Comment: And then the two spaces would be isomorphic ...

Comment: which is contradiction..

Comment: Yes.  Only one is reflexive, e.g.

Comment: but why argument about $\ell^1\subset \ell^2$ is not enough?

Comment: I mean that $\ell^2$ is "larger" than $\ell^1$, so how can $F$ be surjective?

Comment: The sets have the same cardinality, though.

Comment: @user155947: Hint: By that logic, you would think it would be impossible to have a surjective map from the even integers $2\mathbb{Z}$ to the integers $\mathbb{Z}$... but clearly you can.  In some sense that is the whole point of infinite sets.

Comment: ahh ok. It's the same thing as surjection (bijection) from $N$ to $Z$. stupid me

Comment: but why open mapping is needed for isomorphism? I mean isomorphism=injection+surjection yes?

Comment: @user155947 for Banach spaces yes, but how do you know that $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ is not isomorphic?

Comment: and how open mapping theorem helps us here? can you explain a bit more. sorry, im newbie

Comment: The [Bounded Inverse Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem), which is a direct consequence of the Open Mapping Theorem, would imply $F^{-1}$ is continuous, were $F$ surjective. That would imply the two spaces are isomorphic as Banach spaces. (You also need continuity of $F^{-1}$ to say the spaces are isomorphic as Banach spaces.)

Answer (score 5):

The cardinality of $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are the same, even though, as sets, $\ell_1\subset\ell_2$. So, this isn't enough.

However, assume $F$ is surjective. Then the   [Bounded Inverse Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem) would imply that $F^{-1}$ is continuous. This would mean $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are isomorphic Banach spaces.

This however isn't the case. The simplest reason I can think of that shows why this is so is that $\ell_2$ has a separable dual while $\ell_1$ doesn't (if $X$ is isomorphic to $Y$, then $X^*$ is isomorphic to $Y^*$).  You could also argue they can't be isomorphic since only one of them is reflexive.

(Of note is that the range of $F$ can't be closed, since every closed subspace of $\ell_2$ is reflexive.)